# quey posts from different categories with taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query-posts

I wonder if someone could help me.

I just upgrade my wordpress and start to use taxonomy.

what I want to do is to query posts from different categories.

I used to do it like this 
`query_posts('cat=5');`

but with taxonomy added to my categories, doesnt work anymore
for example if I go to a category page the link goes like this

`www.website.com/ad-category/cars`

I guess my taxonomy category name is "ad-category" and the category name is cars

but how could I query posts from categories ids, example 5,6,7,8 etc..

Thak you for your time!!

Comment: Since I don't have time to give a real answer at the moment, I'll leave a comment with the quick answer: use WordPress 3.1-beta. It can do what you're trying to do (ad-category=1,2,3,4 as a query var).

Answer (score 1):

As Bloch commented, 3.1 provides a way to easily accomplish this. Here's a terrific article describing exactly how to execute [advanced taxonomy queries](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/). Here's the [plugin to run the 3.1 beta](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-beta-tester/).

Here is some slightly modified code from an example in the [advanced taxonomy queries](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/) article:

```
$adcatquery = wp_parse_args( $query_string );

$adcatquery['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'ad-category', //custom taxonomy name
        'terms' => array( 'cars', 'trucks', 'whatever' ), //custom taxonomy terms
        'field' => 'slug', //refers to $query_string, may use ID
        'operator' => 'IN' //NOT IN excludes terms
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'model', //custom taxonomy name
        'terms' => array( 'corolla', '4runner' ), //custom taxonomy terms
        'field' => 'slug', //refers to $query_string, may use ID
        'operator' => 'IN' //NOT IN excludes terms
    )
);

query_posts( $adcatquery );
```

This should give you a decent idea (haven't tested it though)... good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it was working for me to grab different post from different taxonomies and doing stuff with them:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME', 'posts_per_page' => 4 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<div class="some-post-class">
do something here
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
```

Using that I was able use that however many times I needed to run though my custom post types.  I ended up going a slightly different route, by adding a foreach loop around the outside and running thru each of my taxonomies to set a variable dynamically.  You can see my post at: [Dynamic variable for custom taxonomy in loop?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5244/dynamic-variable-for-custom-taxonomy-in-loop)